# Displaying an array in view returned from Model CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have below code snippet ,I m new to codeigniter.

In **Model**,I'm returning an array as below

```
      $data[$i] = $query->result_array;
      $i++; 
      return $data;
```

**Controller**:

```
   public function getcity()
   {
         $this->getstate();
         $result1 = $this->result;
             //$result1=$this->getstate();       
         $this->load->model('test_model');                   
         $resultdata = $this->test_model->getcity($result1);
         var_dump($resultdata);
         $output['query']=$resultdata;
             $this->load->view('test_view', $output);                 
    }
```

In **View**:

```
 <?php foreach($query as $val => $row):?>
            <a href="link" style="color:#FF0000" > </a>

            <?php  echo  $row['city_name']."<br />";?>

        <?php  endforeach;?>
```

`vardump` of returned array in model is as below which is same as the value of the array at the time of assigning to a array in controller

```
array (size=27)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'city_name' => string 'Dundee' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'city_name' => string 'Edinbrough' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'city_name' => string 'Oxford' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'city_name' => string 'AAAA' (length=5)
```

With the above view code , I'm getting **error**:

A PHP **Error** was encountered

```
  Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: city_name Filename: views/test_view.php        
  Line Number: 9
```

Please let me know where to change the snippet.

Comment: I guess you should do `$row[0]['city_name']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $data[$i];
```

There is no need for `$i`, because `$data` automatically acts as an array. You can write

```
$data = $query->result_array;

If you use `$i` it acts as a multidimensional array.
In that case you go with $row[0]['city_name'];
```